# Cert validation path error when debugging in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, flutter, keytool

I just generated the sample app from https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab

When i hit the debug button in Android Studio i get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1639)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1621)
... 20 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
... 26 more
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I'm behind an enterprise proxy and already added its certificate to the **cacerts** keystore but i still get the error.

Any ideas about how to solve this?

Comment: I am getting the same error. did you got the resolution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only workaround i found yet is to change the **jcenter()** in **build.gradle** to **mavenCentral()**

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to know, Android Studio has its own jre.

so you need to add certificate to it.

1. find your android studio path and jre/lib/security/cacerts.

   > in my case(windows) : C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\security
2. add certificate

   > keytool -import -alias mycertificate -keystore path_to_keystore -file android studio certificate_file

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error while building flutter sample app.

It is a gradle sync issue. Just try Invalidate cache from studio settings and update distribution url in gradlewrraper.properties file and do resync.